# Get all events of user

Tags: django, google-calendar-api, python-social-auth

So currently I can login and store my refresh token(if need be I can also store the access token) in a db using Google OAuth2 while using python social auth.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Profile(AbstractUser):

    refresh_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
```

I have a url /calendar that needs to retrieve the Google calendar events of the currently logged user. I also have a regular login that if the user has a refresh token which means that he has linked his google account to his account. How would I use get_events to just give all of the events associated with that account.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
def get_events(request):
    print(request.user.refresh_token)
    credentials = Credentials(get_access_token(request), scopes=SCOPES)
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
    google_calendar_events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', singleEvents=True,
                                          orderBy='startTime').execute()
    google_calendar_events = google_calendar_events.get('items', [])
    return google_calendar_events 

def get_access_token(request): 
    social = request.user.social_auth.get(provider='google-oauth2') 
    return social.extra_data['access_token']
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request,'User blocked')
                return redirect('login')
        else:
            messages.error(request,'username or password not correct')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/login.html',{'form':form})
```

Traceback:

```
RefreshError at /calendar
The credentials do not contain the necessary fields need to refresh the access token. You must specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/calendar
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: RefreshError
Exception Value:    
The credentials do not contain the necessary fields need to refresh the access token. You must specify refresh_token, token_uri, client_id, and client_secret.
```

credentials.json

```
{
    "web": {
        "client_id": "-.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "project_id": "=",
        "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
        "client_secret": "-",
        "redirect_uris": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/", "http://localhost:8000/oauth/complete/google-oauth2/"],
        "javascript_origins": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000", "http://localhost:8000"]
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the current issue of your script?

Comment: It's how to refresh the access token by the refresh token. It won't display the current user's calendar events.

Comment: I added the traceback. It's most likely credentials = Credentials(get_access_token(request), scopes=SCOPES)

Comment: Thank you for replying. Your question is to retrieve the access token using the refresh token. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, what is `How would I use get_events to just give all of the events associated with that account.`? And, in your script, you have already been able to retrieve the refresh token. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, request.user_refresh_token is the value of the refresh token  as well.

Comment: I also have a credentials.json file that contains a  token_uri, client_id, and client_secret if that is correct which was used for login.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that `credentials.json` might be the JSON file downloaded from the Google site. In your situation, for example, the refresh token is put in a file or a variable? Or, the refresh token is put in `credentials.json`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242021/discussion-between-arundeep-chohan-and-tanaike).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following replying,

> It's most likely credentials = Credentials(get_access_token(request), scopes=SCOPES)

> request.user_refresh_token is the value of the refresh token as well.

> I also have a credentials.json file that contains a token_uri, client_id, and client_secret if that is correct which was used for login.

And, your question is to retrieve the access token using the refresh token. In this case, in order to retrieve the access token, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

If `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token` and `token_uri` are put in a variable, you can use the following script.

```py
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

credentials = Credentials(
    token=None,
    client_id="###", # Please set the cliend ID.
    client_secret="###", # Please set client secret.
    refresh_token='###', # Please set refresh token.
    token_uri="###" # Please set token URI.
)
credentials.refresh(Request())
access_token = credentials.token
print(access_token)

# If you want to use the following script, you can use it.
# service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

Or, if `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token` and `token_uri` are put in a file, you can use the following script.

```py
tokenFile = '###' # Please set the filename with the path.
credentials = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(tokenFile) # or, Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(tokenFile, scopes)
credentials.refresh(Request())
access_token = credentials.token
print(access_token)

# If you want to use the following script, you can use it.
# service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

#### Reference:

- [google.oauth2.credentials module](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/google.oauth2.credentials.html)

Comment: It's giving me a Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_id, client_secret, refresh_token.

Comment: @Arundeep Chohan Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `It's giving me a Authorized user info was not in the expected format, missing fields client_id, client_secret, refresh_token.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Arundeep Chohan By the way, in order to retrieve the access token from the refresh token, the client ID and the client secret are required to be used. And, when I test `Credentials()`, when `token` and `token_uri` are not used, an error occurs. So I added them.

Comment: I did use the first one and it worked manually setting it might be an issue with how it's structured,

Comment: Would it be better to set those values off in the  config vars.

Comment: @Arundeep Chohan When I think of your situation, I also think so.